# iframe size in according to image

Tags: html, css, iframe

Is it possibile to keep iframe size and position like an image ?

http://federicomalagoni.it/

The light gray view it's an example of iframe, the site is responsive so I need the iframe size and position in according to the image (the iframe have to be place onto the iphone screen image).
Like that:

[image]

I've tried to fix the iframe into the right position but on a change size of the page they don't follow at the same way iphone image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `position: relative` and `position:absolute` and then calculating the percentage position of the screen inside the background-picture.

```css
div {
  float: left;
}
.phone {
  background: url(http://federicomalagoni.it/images/iphone6.png);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 201.1848341%;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
}
iframe {
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  width: 87.2%;
  height: 77.856%;
  top: 11.54%;
  left: 6.2%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;">
  <div class="phone"><iframe src="#"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div style="width:150px;">
  <div class="phone"><iframe src="#"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div style="width:200px;">
  <div class="phone"><iframe src="#"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a different type of responsive. can you explain me? malagoni.federico at gmail dot com

Comment: You would have to place the phones inside a div and then apply the width you need. something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7uco3hue/1/embedded/result/ ... also use mediaqueries if you don't want 4 in a row on mobile, hence you can set the width to 50% or 100% if size is smaller than 768px for example.